# Multiple file download crashes in Firefox using MouseEvent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Using a JavaScript MouseEvent to trigger file download is crashing in Firefox. But works in Chrome. Is there something different that needs to be done in Firefox. Or is there another alternative to do this in Firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/katzmopolitan/L2mL5ktr/5/

```
  var save = document.createElement('a');
  save.href = fileURL;
  save.target = '_blank';
  save.download = "onion";
  var evt = new MouseEvent('build');

  evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  save.dispatchEvent(evt);


  var save = document.createElement('a');
  save.href = fileURL;
  save.target = '_blank';
  save.download = "onion";
  var evt = new MouseEvent('build');

  evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  save.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: I tried this in several Firefox versions (including the current 38.0.1 on Mac and Windows) and Firefox did never crash. It always works. Do you have special Add-ons enabled?

Comment: @Alex Tried at nighlty , appeared to display  save as dialog with file ending in .csv.zip twice ?

Comment: @guest271314 Oh, you're right. But that's only because of a typo in the example. Two variables (fileURL and fileURL1) are created, but variable fileURL is used for both downloads.

Comment: @Alex Change "typo" and expected results returned ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, if I fix the typo everything works as expected. Firefox opens a download window for each file and doesn't crash.

Comment: @Alex Changed to `fileURL1` at http://jsfiddle.net/L2mL5ktr/7/ . Appear same result ; two "Save as" dialog , first file name ?

Comment: @guest271314 Your updated fiddle works. I get the two *different* downloads. But I think that's not the problem here. katzmopolitan wrote the "download is crashing in Firefox". Let's wait if disabling his Add-ons helps or he can update his question.

Comment: @Alex Yes, agreed. Could not reproduce _"download is crashing in Firefox."_

Comment: @Alex you're right, one of the Add-ons was causing the crash! Thank you both. I still have another problem with bulk download, but that is out side of the scope of this question